# How to enable MS SQL drivers in PHP?

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2012, driver

I'm running Windows 7 + PHP 5.6.26 + SQL Server 2012. I have an application which currently uses MySQL, but I need to strip that out and replace it with Microsoft SQL Server. I'm having difficulties simply getting the drivers to install, however.

According to [this link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098), SQLSRV32.EXE contains the drivers for PHP 5.4 - 5.6.

I downloaded the exe and ran the file, extracted to `C:\php\ext`. I then opened `C:\php\php.ini` and scrolled down to the `Dynamic Extensions` section and added this line: `extension=php_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll`.

When I run `phpinfo()`, there is no `sqlsrv` section listed.

I also tried the thread safe version (`php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll`) but that made a difference.

So how do I install the MS SQL drivers for PHP?

As an aside, when I get this sorted out and working , the application will ultimately reside on a Windows Server 2016 machine with PHP 5.6.33 installed, so I'll [probably] need to adjust the drivers I'm using but for now I'd be happy just to get it working locally.

Comment: Sure I saw you already did that, my bad in speed reading hehe :) That being said, one usually has to restart the web server for the changes to the php configuration to take effect.

Comment: @CraigvanTonder Ugh, yea, that's all it was. Forgot to restart IIS. Mondays :)

Comment: Oeh, one of those hey; glad that it was resolved!